# JS Error thrown due to use of default parameter values in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have some js/javascript that runs fine in edge, chrome, firefox and safari. When testing in IE11 it returns `: Expected ')'`

I believe it's because of the use of `function(oTR = null)` however, how can this be? Surely IE11 supports such syntax/logic?!

Here is a link to [MS error page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/misc/expected-right-parenthesis-javascript) that the console produces

```
oSC = {
  oItems : {
    oTR: null,
  },
  GetProductKey : function(oTR = null){
    return $((oTR ? oTR:oSC.oItems.oTR)).attr("data-code");
  },
}
```

Comment: `Surely IE11 supports such syntax/logic?` Nope. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility

Comment: nooooooooooo!!!

Comment: Well surely you just try it without `= null` and if it works, then you know what the problem is and that it isn't supported

Comment: funnily enough I've tested that and it works.... I guess I was looking for confirmation and suggestions as to how to mitigate, polyfill etc. Unsure why you feel the need to downvote. Could you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a simple condition to your ternary Operator

```
oSC = {
  oItems : {
    oTR: null,
  },
  GetProductKey : function(oTR){
    return $((typeof oTR === 'YOUR_EXPECTED_TYPE' ? oTR :oSC.oItems.oTR)).attr("data-code");
 },
}
```

Comment: thanks Chris! This is a nice idea, just check the type and will allow me to still pass my null values. What a PITA though! Could you explain why people have downvoted this question?

Comment: As OP is checking for null, then you can use a logical OR operator as a null coalesce: `return $(oTR || oTR:oSC.oItems.oTR).data('code');`. Also note that one set of parentheses are redundant, and you should use the `data()` method when accessing `data` attributes

Comment: Yes when you expect null then this is a shorter way to get the right value:  `oTR || oSC.oItems.oTR` . But make sure you dont expect other values like 0 or false.... then `oSC.oItems.oTR` always win

Comment: thanks guys very helpful. Will try it out now! Can anyone explain why my post has been downvoted? Tired of it happening to what I feel is a genuine question

Comment: Probably most developers are using things like babel to avoid this kind of problems. And so most people can not imagine to have this kind of problem. It can be really hard to write cross-browser code that works everywhere. So maybe you should give babel a try: https://babeljs.io/

Comment: thanks chrisheyn, will check it out. Still frustrating a post that may be of use to other is down-voted. Thanks again for your help.